# Do I need to replace the anti-siphon valve?

Tags: faucet, outdoor

We had a hard freeze and even though my faucets were covered, I think the anti-siphon valve may be damaged. The faucet itself seems to be ok, I dont see any leaks. When I turn on the faucet, water streams from the holes in the valve, does this mean I need to replace the valve? Is this difficult to replace?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That's a hose bibb vacuum breaker that's doing that, and it's shot

What you have there is a conventional hose bibb (outdoor faucet) that's been retrofitted with a *hose bibb vacuum breaker* to prevent a water main break from sucking whatever you left your garden hose in into the city's water system.  Unfortunately, with most of these retrofit-type devices, you need to drain them manually in order to winterize them, and if you don't, they may break, as yours clearly has.  You'll need to find and drill out the locking setscrew that holds yours on, then remove it and replace it with a new hose bibb vacuum breaker -- they're available at any hardware store.

Comment: That is super helpful, thanks TPE! I have questions though. (1) how do I drain it to prevent this from happening in the future? (2) how do I drill it out? I dont think it has a screw that you tighten to keep it on, I believe it is screwed onto the faucet. (3) can you recommend a quality breaker to replace this with?

Comment: @amrog -- 1) is trivial (just push the little "nipple" on the bottom aside), 2) is something you'll have to figure out (there's a good chance the setscrew was broken off to keep someone from removing it in a fit of haste, but if it just unthreads, that's fine too), and 3) I personally use a Cash Acme VB-222 as it's designed to self-drain when you remove the hose from the bibb